# swift documentation for an override func

Tags: ios, swift, documentation

There is great help here for how to document a func in swift using ///

But how about for an override func?

When I option-click I only get the original documentation of animationDidStop (declared in CAAnimation).

Here is my code. (taken from ViewController.swift a UIViewController which is declared as the delegate for an animation created in another function)

```
/// called when dripStreamStart() finishes
/// in order to continue the animation
/// 
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
    dripStreamsOscillate()
}
```

Thanks very much for your help.